# Should we turn off [automatic-updates]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I believe [automatic-updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automatic-updates) deserves burnination treatment for being useless.

Specifically, it violates these two criteria:

- **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** Barely, if at all.
- **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** Absolutely not. Questions are not related to any specific auto-update technology but are all over the place: Windows, Linux, Java, app servers, iTunes, even spreadsheets.

Some questions could possibly be retagged with [windows-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-update) or similar specific technologies but most don't need one at all.

Comment: or how about: manual deletion of [automatic-updates]

Comment: It's kinda project specific. As long as I fully agree w with second point, for the first point, it allows segregation of questions by information about them, and in my opinion, the `automatic-updates` tag  Assume you're using automatic update framework for Java and it fails at some point - tagging the question with automatic-updates is really in place.